# Keeping Unique Rows with Group By Cube

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have data that includes the SSN of a student, the college campus they attended, and their wages for a given year. Like so...

```
create table #thetable (SSN int, campus int, wage int);

insert into #thetable(SSN, campus, wage)
values
(111111111,1,100),
(111111111,2,100),
(222222222,1,250),
(222222222,2,250),
(333333333,1,50),
(444444444,2,400);
```

Now, I want to get the average wage of the students at each campus, and the average wage of students from all campuses put together... So I do something like this:

```
select campus, avg(wage)
from #thetable
group by cube(campus);
```

The problem is that I don't want to double-count the students who attended two campuses when I'm grouping the campuses together. This is the output I'm getting (double counts students 111111111 and 2222222222):

```
Campus   (no column name)
1        133
2        250
NULL     191
```

My desired output is this (no double counting):

```
Campus   (no column name)
1        133
2        250
NULL     200
```

Can this be accomplished without using multiple queries and the `UNION` operator? If so, how? (Incidentally, I realize that this table is not normalized... would normalizing help?)

Comment: I fussed around with CTEs--technically, a single query--but couldn't avoid UNION and multiple full table scans. Barring funkiness with the various CUBE operators (which I've never used), I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Without UNION and subqueries. this seems to be difficult/not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with a correlated sub-query. Works for me.

```
select campus,
(
    select avg(wage)
    from 
    (
        select ssn, campus, wage, row_number() over(partition by SSN order by wage) as RN
        from #thetable as inside
        where (inside.campus=outside.campus or outside.campus is null) 
    ) as middle
    where RN=1
)
from #thetable outside
group by cube(campus);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with one column.  The `cube` is going to rollup the values based on the calculations on each line.  So, if a row is included in one calculation, it will be included in the sum.

You can do this, though, by weighting the values by 1 divided by the frequency.  This "divides" a student equally across the campuses to each adds to 1:

```
select campus, avg(wage) as avg_wage, sum(wage*weight) / sum(weight) avg_wage_weighted
from (select t.*, (1.0 / count(*) over (partition by SSN)) as weight
      from #thetable t
     ) t
group by cube(campus);
```

The second column should be the value you want.  You can then embed this further in a subquery to get one column:

```
select campus, (case when campus is null then avg_wage_weighted else avg_wage end)
from (select campus, avg(wage) as avg_wage, sum(wage*weight) / sum(weight) avg_wage_weighted
      from (select t.*, (1.0 / count(*) over (partition by SSN)) as weight
            from #thetable t
           ) t
      group by cube(campus)
     ) t
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1bdad/4) is a SQL Fiddle showing the solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Definitely works when there's only one dimension that you're using cube on, but unfortunately my actual use case has multiple dimensions... Campus, Degree Type, Area of Study. Now, obviously, I could still use this approach, but it would get exponentially more complex as the number of dimensions increased... I think I'll stick with the correlated sub-query. Its obviously slow by definition, but I'm willing ot deal with that given the situation at hand.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom . . . The idea of weighting the rows, so all rows add up to 1 for an individual, should work across multiple dimensions.

Comment: Right. Like I said, I could still use the approach, it would just get significantly more complex. If there's 3 dimensions, then I would need to calculate 7 different weights to account for all of the different ways that the grouping variables could be rolled up, 4 dimensions would require 15 different weights, etc. It gets out of hand quickly.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom . . . I think you can only apply the weights once.  The partitioning clause is the person id (`SSN`) not the dimensions being used for the `cube`.